# Sharp Edges using Bevel Emboss in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So I was trying to make a metalic look using the bevel emboss when I stumbled on this strange pixelated edges in the middle of my fonts. I tried changing fonts no matter which one I took they kept having the same issue. Also tried loading in the font as a illustrator vector but same thing happens there. Tried changing bevel emboss settings, but nothing really helps.

PSD download link: https://www.mediafire.com/?8fb7za576o41u85

Im using photoshop cs6.
Here is a picture of my issue:
[image: sharp edges inside the marked areas]

Comment: The problem could be related to the layer styles you use. Please provide us more information or upload the psd so we can have a look.

Comment: Here is my PSD: https://www.mediafire.com/?8fb7za576o41u85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the shine stroke. You chose: [image]

This is creating edges that are too hard. Try to use something smoother like: [image]

It should look like this now: [image]

Comment: You are correct, thanks a lot!
I didn't think about the contour.

Comment: It smoothened the edges, but it still remains grainy, there is no way to fully remove it?

Comment: I added picture of how it should look now with the changes. Can you highlight where it is still grainy? You wont get better results at this font size with the round characters C and S because, well, they are round :) If you try a bigger font it could be better.

Comment: Yeah indeed its the round and the angled characters like the N / M that look grainy but I guess thats photoshops limit, maybe making the text in a 3D renderer would work better. And again thanks for taking your time much appreciated.